# Initialize the eight working variables SHA256

Tags: implementation, sha-256

I have a little confusion in understanding explanation of SHA256 by FIPS

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`

are being initialized as (this is what i don't understand)

> 2 . Initialize the eight working variables, $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,$ and $h$, with the $(i-1)^{st}$ hash value:
>
> $\ \ \ \ a = H_0^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ b = H_1^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ c = H_2^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ d = H_3^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ e = H_4^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ f = H_5^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ g = H_6^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ h = H_7^{(i-1)}$

cause with this, in stage 1 of iteration, variables

`a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h`

would have (pre-defined) **Initial Values of H**. But in Calculation Stage of these variables there is no use of next stage Intermediate Hash Values H.

> 3 . $For\ t=0\ to\ 63:$
>   $\ \ \ \ \{$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ T_1=h+\sum_1^{\{256\}}(e)+Ch(e,f,g)+K_t^{\{256\}}+W_t$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ T_2=\sum_0^{\{256\}}(a)+Maj(a,b,c)$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ h=g$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g=f$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ f=e$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ e=d+T_1$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ d=c$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c=b$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ b=a$
>   $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a=T_1+T_2$
>   $\ \ \ \ \}$

and what I see Intermediate Values are calculated with Variables not the other way around.

> 4 . Compute the $i^{th}$ intermediate hashvalue $H^{(i)}$:
>
> $\ \ \ \ H_0^{(i)}=a+H_0^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_1^{(i)}=b+H_1^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_2^{(i)}=c+H_2^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_3^{(i)}=d+H_3^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_4^{(i)}=e+H_4^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_5^{(i)}=f+H_5^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_6^{(i)}=g+H_6^{(i-1)}$
>    $\ \ \ \ H_7^{(i)}=h+H_7^{(i-1)}$

Can you please explain to me how 2. Stage (Initialization) fit in Iteration Process of SHA256.

Comment: I looked that code again.! It says the same thing but simpler though.. So You agree with it that we should initialize both variables (a b c d....h) and intermediate values (H0-H7) with same pre-defined initial values ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` are assigned on each *round* of the compression function main loop, but the interim hash values are considered only per *message chunk* (i.e. after all rounds have completed)

I found the [Wikipedia pseudo-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) easier to understand than the description in your question, and it is clear there how the variables relate to interim hash values. Note where your reference relates previous hash components $H_0^{(i)}=a+H_0^{(i-1)}$ the pseudocode just assigns `h0 = a + h0`, because there is no need to keep previous hash values, just a current one which is updated after processing each chunk.

Just before calculating the rounds for the each chunk, both the *current* `H` array and `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` hold the same data. This changes during calculation of the rounds, and you need to keep the value of `H` so it can be added back in at the end of the chunk.

When starting the first message chunk, before any processing rounds, `H` *and* `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` hold the "initial values of H" (based on square roots of first 8 primes). You do not use those initial values again.

Comment: So, H and Variables would be initialized with same values and on 1st round Variables would be calculated and added with H values (which would still have initial values)! and for Next 512_block H values would be preserved but Variables would be re-initialized with (pre-defined) initial values. please just verify this.

Comment: Not quite. For each message chunk, `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h` are set to *current* (interim) hash. Only for the first message iteration will this be the same as the initial hash.

Comment: and this `i` represents the 512_block or chunk number, not the round (iteration) number? i.e: H and calculated Variables are only added once for 1 chunk. Not after every iteration. right?

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes. With i=0 being initial values.

Comment: Thanx Man! I gotta submit this my semester project tomorrow. Really appreciate quick reply.